# Map values is private when called from class instance

Tags: dart

My Dart code is giving me this error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no getter 'myKey'
```

Here is my code:

```
Class A{
        Map a = {
             "myKey": "Dont privatise this value"};
}
Main(){
     A b = new A();
     print(b.a.myKey);  // Error
     print(b.a['myKey']); // Error too..
}
```

I already searched this problem but I don't understand why the compiler doesn't want to give me `myKey` from the map. But I already checked in the Dart console (by print method in the class constructor) and I am sure the key `myKey` is in the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dart, you cannot access `Map` values using the dot-notation. It is an error to evaluate `b.a.myKey` since `Map`s do not have a `myKey` getter. However, `b.a['myKey']` shouldn't be an error. A quick check in dartpad shows that it will work: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/10cdcbdc3730cfec175174e675320e54

Comment: Indeed you are right, when I used the syntax ["myKey"] there was a different error, I thought I had really checked everything, a big thank you for that Harry

Comment: Forgive but do you know an alternative to use the syntax first?

Comment: You could do 

    `class A {
      final String myKey = "Dont privatise this value";
    }`